# Android Studio SDK version error after update

Tags: android, sdk, android-studio, development-environment

I just finished installing Android Studio and the JDK. Everything worked fine while I looked around the new interface. No errors or anything. After I checked for updates I went from version 0.5.2 to 0.6. When I restarted I got the error

> Error:The SDK Build Tools revision (19.0.3) is too low for project ':app'. Minimum required is 19.1.0

Which SDK is it referring to and shouldn't it update along with Android Studio? Before I updated I did not have this message.

Comment: Can you post your gradle file?

Comment: All files are default. What is the name of the file that I am looking for? gradlew.bat, gradlew, build.gradle?

Comment: I know what your problem is! See my answer

Answer (score 46, accepted):

So Android Studio version 0.6 requires the Android SDK build tools to be 19.1 instead of the old 19.0.3.

To install this, follow these steps:

1. Close all open projects.
2. On the main Android Studio window, press `Configure`
3. Then click `SDK Manager`

Once inside find the following build tools version:

[image: Build tools needed]

Then tick the box and install the package.

Once your done with that, close the SDK Manager, restart Android Studio, and you should be good to go!

## EDIT:

One more thing you need to do:

1. Open your project.
2. Navigate to your `build.gradle` file located inside your module. For you, I think it's in the `app` folder.
3. Open the file.

Now you should see something like this:
[image: gradle file]

Where it says `buildToolsVersion` in the quotes, replace `19.0.3` with `19.1.0`. Now sync gradle files and everything should be solved.

Comment: I installed it but I still get the same error. Should I be deleting the old 19.0.1?

Comment: See my edited answer. I forgot to include the gradle instructions.

Comment: Created a new project and those settings (compileSdkVersion and buildToolsVersion) don't exist in the build.gradle file.

Comment: Are you in the root folder of your module? You should have an "app" module which is where the gradle file you want is.